Firebase Phone Authentication with Flutter: reCAPTCHA Configuration Issue in Production
I am implementing phone authentication in my Flutter app using Firebase. The app has already been published on Google Play, and I've configured the signing keys in the Firebase project, linked the Google Cloud project to Play Integrity, and provided debug tokens in the Firebase project for development purposes.
However, I am facing an issue with reCAPTCHA during the authentication process. I am getting errors indicating that reCAPTCHA has not been correctly initialized. Here are the relevant logs:
  E/zzb     (22098): Failed to initialize reCAPTCHA config: No Recaptcha Enterprise siteKey configured for tenant/project
  E/FirebaseAuth(22098): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 18002 Invalid PlayIntegrity token; app not Recognized by Play Store.
  E/zzb     (22098): Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [There was an internal error in the web widget. {"code":"auth/internal-error","message":"Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked."}]```

I have already included the necessary dependencies in my app's build.gradle file:


implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0')
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity')
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug")```
And my initialization code looks like this:
if (!foundation.kIsWeb) {
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
    appleProvider: AppleProvider.appAttest,
    webProvider: ReCaptchaV3Provider(kWebRecaptchaSiteKey),
  );
} else {
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
    appleProvider: AppleProvider.debug,
    webProvider: ReCaptchaV3Provider(kWebRecaptchaSiteKey),
  );
}

The kWebRecaptchaSiteKey is also defined in my code. Despite this, I keep encountering the reCAPTCHA initialization error, which seems to suggest a misconfiguration somewhere in the process.
Questions:
How do I correctly configure reCAPTCHA for Firebase phone authentication in a Flutter app that has been published on Google Play?
Is there a step I might have missed in setting up reCAPTCHA Enterprise for my Firebase project or within the Flutter app itself?
Given the error logs, is there a specific configuration for the siteKey that I need to adjust in the Firebase console or the Google Cloud Platform?
Any guidance or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated, as it's critical for the authentication process in my app.
